# Missing information from Google Open ID

Tags: php, openid

I am using php lightopenID on my website for authenticating Google Users. I require the email address, firstname and lastname. It works 99% of the time but there are couple of time when it I dont get the required information, sometimes the firstname and or lastname is empty.

I assume the reason I am getting empty firstname and empty lastname is because the user forgot to put those details in his google account but then I think why will Google allow such thing to happen. Is my assumption correct?

Is there something I can do from the server side when Google does not return the firstname/lastname?

Comment: You can't force people to give you personal information.

Comment: I thought name and email are shared by default using open id. The 1% of users which do not share their information are not allowed to log in. So they send an email and I have to update the info manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something I can do from the server side when Google does not
>   return the firstname/lastname?

Prompt them to enter there name, or assign them as User123456 like here on stackoverflow.

You should design your app to work even for people that dont want to share, @MathieuImbert is correct you should not force personal info from your user. create an engaging site/interface and encourage your user to complete a profile.

Comment: Yes this is a great idea, if any of the name fields are empty I will prompt the user to enter it. Thanks